# Spark streaming - What happens to a Future after an RDD was totally finished?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, future

**The question is the following:** What happens to a `Future` after a batch finishes in Spark ?

I have an application that reads from a `Kafka` topic and writes to another one. Here is the main code:

```
KafkaUtils
  .createDirectStream[String, SomeClass](options...)
  .foreachPartition(
    partition => {
      doSomeWork(partition)
    }
  )
```

and inside `doSomeWork` there is a point where I request some info from a database and get a `Future` back to handle. 
What happens to the future if I don't `Await.result` it ? is it garbage collected ? or can I still receive response with an `onSuccess` callback ?

**Investigation:** 
After having investigated with the team, we noticed that futures get Garbage collected after transformation. 
When in a action, a future can be completed afterward (during next batch) and the `onSuccess` DO get called.

Comment: Spark assumes that tasks are written in synchronous way, so your code would be executed and becomes subject for garbage collection. Only data could be marked for persistance.